# How to combine multiple csv files into one dataframe in R when datatype for some columns are different in each csv file

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, types, merge

I'm very new to R programming and I'm currently trying to merge 12 csv files that I have into 1 dataframe.

The issue I'm facing is that all the datatype for columns aren't the same across all the csv files. So for Example : start_time is datetime in some csv files and character in others. Or start_id is character in some files and numeric in others.

I initially thought I could just convert all the columns into character type and store the data in one dataframe and them convert the columns which are of other datatypes later. But that doesn't sound like a good solution.

Any suggestions as to what I can do to be able to solve this.

To give a better understanding, this is the error I'm facing for the following code

```
    files <- list.files(path = "D:/OneDrive/Documents/01_CyclisticBike_BikeTripData_202011-202110_v1/RMarkdown_notes/TripData/", pattern = ".csv" )

files <- str_c("D:/OneDrive/Documents/01_CyclisticBike_BikeTripData_202011-202110_v1/RMarkdown_notes/TripData/", files)
files


    for ( i in 1:length(files)){
      nam <- paste("df",i, sep = "") 
      assign(nam, read_csv(file = files[i] , col_types = cols((.default = "c"), start_station_id = "i", end_station_id = "i", started_at = "T", ended_at = "T")))
      
    }
    
    bikeTrip <- rbind(df1, df2, df3)
```

Error: For some reason in Getting NA for started_at and ended_at columns. I was hoping it would make the column's class datetime.

Comment: Have you tried setting the data type for each column using the `col_types` argument in `read_csv`?

Comment: I'm majorly now facing issue with datetime. This is the code I'm using : df <- read_csv(file = files[i], col_types = cols((.default = "c"), start_station_id = "i", end_station_id = "i", started_at = "T", ended_at = "T")) ----------------- The main issue I'm now seeing is that, it is giving NA for the started_at and ended_at columns

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, otherwise, it is impossible to help with your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example